# msal.js v2.3 acquireTokenSilent returning empty access token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am upgrading an app using msal.js v1.3 to v2.3 and I'm having a problem retreiving the access token once I get my id token.

I initialize the handleRedirectPromise in my constructor. Then, when the user clicks the login button, I call loginRedirect and pass in an object that has the openid scope and the scope from my separately registered api. This works well, the id token comes back and I call acquireTokenSilent to retreive my access token. I pass an object that has my registered api's scope and account from the loginRedirect call into this function.

The problem is that the authorization response from the acquireTokenSilent has an empty access token. The result from the token endpoint looks like:

```
client_info: "xx"
id_token: "xx"
not_before: 1602895189
refresh_token: "xx"
refresh_token_expires_in: 1209600
scope: ""
token_type: "Bearer"
```

It doesn't have an access token, but it does specifiy the token type as `Bearer`
There is no access token in the response and it looks like the scopes property returning is empty. Here is my code:

```js
    private msalConfig: Msal.Configuration = {
        auth: {
            clientId: environment.clientID,
            authority: 'https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_DefaultSignInSignUp',
            knownAuthorities: ['<tenant>.b2clogin.com'],
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, 
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
        }
    };
    private loginRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest = {
        scopes: ['openid' ,  'offline_access', 'https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read' ] 
    };

    private accessTokenRequest: Msal.SilentRequest = {
        scopes:  ['https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read'] ,
        account: null
        
    };
 constructor() {
        const _this = this;
        this.msalInstance = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(this.msalConfig);
        this.aquireSilent = (request: Msal.SilentRequest): Promise<Msal.AuthenticationResult> => {
            return _this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(
                access_token => {
                    _this.cacheExpiration(access_token.expiresOn);
                    _this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
                    return access_token;
                },
                function (reason) {
                    console.error(reason);
                },
            );
        };

        this.msalInstance
            .handleRedirectPromise()
            .then((tokenResponse: Msal.AuthenticationResult) => {
                if (tokenResponse !== null) {
                    const id_token = tokenResponse.idToken;
                    const currentAccounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts()
                    this.accessTokenRequest.account = currentAccounts[0];
                    this.aquireSilent(this.accessTokenRequest)
                } 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    public login() {
        this.msalInstance.loginRedirect(this.loginRequest);
    }
```

Why is the access token not coming back from the token endpoint? Does it have to do with the scopes returning empty? I tried removing the scopes and putting in invalid entries and an error gets raised so I know my request going out is at least valid. Also, just to verify, I have 2 app registrations in AAD, one I created for my spa that has code flow and my older registration I have for my api with an exposed api and scope.

Comment: Without a scope in the auth request, there is no access token acquired.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT which part is the auth Request? Both my loginRequest and my accessToken request parameters have scopes. Do I need to add it to my b2c configuration as well?

Comment: Your code looks good actually. Check the Application storage (session+local) in the Browsers dev tools to see if MSAL has thrown an error

Comment: No errors. Also the request is a valid one. Above I listed the result from the token endpoint which is called when acquireTokenSilent is invoked. That doesn't have an access token on it, so it makes be believe there is something wrong with my original request or my app registration.

Comment: The result from the auth call to openid-configuration has a property in it `scopes_supported: [
    "openid"
  ]` It doesn't have the scope from my exposed api. Could this be the issue?

Comment: no not the issue. when you look at the network request, you should see `scope=openid offline_access https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read`. The app registration denoted by the client_id in the auth request, must have permission to the scope `https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read`. You configure that permission in the portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions

Comment: I just gave the app registration permission to the scope, but that didn't work. I have 2 app registrations. One I assume is for the main client app and one is to expose an api.  I looked at the registration used for my api, it is old and uses implicit flow. Could this be the problem? Do I need 2 app registrations? Can I just expose the api on my client app?

Comment: You need  2 app reg's as per the doc. Make sure to click Grant Permissions also. You should also use the "Run Now" link in the Portal against your User Flow and select the App and then select the Access Token drop down box. Use a reply url for https://jwt.ms and you should see the access token in the URL after signing in. If this works, then the problem is with MSAL code.

Comment: I do have the api permission added (I haven't granted admin consent) for the exposed api in the client app.  I used the "Run Now" link against my user flow and used jwt.ms as the reply url and the access token was in the url and populated in the jwt interface.

Comment: The populated value in jwt.ms is the id token. You need to put the url in notepad to see if access token also returned. You must click grant admin consent. Follow the document exactly.

Comment: It worked! I granted consent and that did the trick. Thanks @JasSuri-MSFT

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, If you want to add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I struggled with this and followed all the suggestions above. What finally worked was just to DELETE the existing scope on the api and start again! After granting consent, then I was able to obtain the access token.

Answer (score 5):

`acquireTokenSilent` will return an access token only if there is already an entry for that token in the cache. So if for some reason the token was never obtained previously (via `loginRedirect`, for instance), it will not be able to acquire it *silently*.

That seems to be the issue in your case. You are mixing scopes for different resources in your `loginRequest`, and that's perhaps causing the issue in the new version of the library (access tokens are issued *per-resource-per-scope(s)*. See this [doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md) for more) Try modifying your `loginRequest` object like this:

```js
  private loginRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest = {
       scopes: ['openid',  'offline_access' ],
       extraScopesToConsent:['https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read']

   };
```

Also, the recommended pattern of usage with `acquireTokenSilent` is that you should fall back to an interactive method (e.g. `acquireTokenRedirect`) if the `acquireTokenSilent` fails for some reason.

So I would modify it as:

```js
    this.aquireSilent = (request: Msal.SilentRequest): Promise<Msal.AuthenticationResult> => {
        return _this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(
            access_token => {
                 // fallback to interaction when response is null
                 if (access_token === null) {
                   return _this.msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
                 }
                _this.cacheExpiration(access_token.expiresOn);
                _this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
                return access_token;
            },
            function (reason) {          
               if (reason instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                  // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
                  return _this.msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
               } else {
                  console.warn(reason);   
               }
            },
        );
    };
```

A similar issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2315#issuecomment-706382855)

Comment: Thanks @derisen, I added the acquireTokenRedirect and extraScopesToConsent to my code. JasSuri pointed out I needed to grant admin consent in my client api and it worked. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for all of your help!