# I can't get accessToken via requireTokenSilent @azure/msal-browser

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I'm recently trying to get accessToken from AzureADB2C with "acquireTokenSilent Flow".
I'm using @azure/msal-browser and my app is React.
So, now my code is like this.

```
    const getTokenRedirect = async (account, apiConfig) => {
        publicClient.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: apiConfig.scopes,
            account: account,
            authority: apiConfig.authority,
        }).then(tokenResponse => {
            console.log(tokenResponse);
            setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken);
        }).catch(async (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

Then this code response refresh token, not accessToken.
I have no idea why acquireTokenSilent didn't  response accessToken.
I did get idToken from ADB2C. And another sample (msal.js vanilla Sample) got accessToken.
So I think B2C setting is correct. My code has some problems.

Does anybody know solution for like this.

Comment: apiConfig = URI +scopes (I set my app on app registry panel on this uri is exposed . and scopes is set also at scopes panel. It's like https://[mywebapplicationURI]/[scopes] . This one is not b2c policy URL. But I got refresh token anyway.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64417515) answer your question?

Comment: Hi Tiny-wa. Thank you for your comment. I found this issue https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2315 . I think this problem is same of mine.

Comment: okay, the link you provided also gives a solution that using both acquireTokenSilent and acquireTokenRedirect. Hope you to solve it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using *@azure/msal-browser* version **2.20.0** and am getting an access token now that I have configured the request passed to `acquireTokenSilent` correctly. Check that any scopes included in the request use the full path name of the scope, not just the short name. In my case I have an API permission which I see in Azure AD B2C is named `https://MYAPPNAME.onmicrosoft.com/MYAPPNAME-development/demo.read`, so the scope name needs to be set to that long name, not the short version of just `demo.read`.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the version of msal-browser, and the accessToken cannot be returned in versions after 2.1.0.

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2315#issuecomment-706382855) of the B2C service currently [tracked here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/FAQ.md#why-is-there-no-access-token-returned-from-acquiretokensilent), and Microsoft should fix it in the future.